# JavaScript Glossary: Value vs Expression?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the two terms. 
What I understand till now, an expression is any piece of code that produces a value.
But in the program, what should I call this:

```
5;
```

A value or an expression? Or can I use the two terms interchangeably?

Comment: The word *value* usually means some single value. The word "expression" means something like `5 + 2 * x`; a *formula* of some sort. In JavaScript, the two words often are used to mean the same thing because expressions are *evaluated* and the result is a *value*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **value** is essentially anything assigned to a variable.

According to **[EloquentJavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html)**:

> There are six basic types of values in JavaScript: numbers, strings, Booleans, objects, functions, and undefined values.

According to **[2ality](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)**:

> An **expression** produces a value and can be written wherever a value is expected, for example as an argument in a function call. Each of the following lines contains an expression:
>
> ```
> myvar
> 3 + x
> myfunc("a", "b")
> ```

So in short, an **expression** is anything that can be evaluated; the **result** of that evaluation is a **value**.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "An expression is anything that can hold value after the expression is evaluated..." — huh?  I mean, you obviously know the answer, but that statement doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: ^ I've updated that wording to hopefully make it slightly clearer. It's a little difficult considering they're so similar :)

Comment: Yes that looks great :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ObsidianAge. So this `5;` is one of JavaScript **value** types(_number_) and because it produces a value it's an **expression**. Did I get it?

Comment: It's just a straight out **value**, as there's nothing to 'evaluate'. `5 + 5` is an expression; `10` is a value :)